# What is the letter of experience for faculty position?

Tags: job, faculty-application, application-cover-letter

I am going to apply for a faculty position. One the required documents is titled" Letter of Experience". Do you know what is this letter. Is there any special format for that? Need to say, they have also asked for a formal application letter.

Comment: What country is it?

Comment: If unsure what they mean by it, write to them! There is going to be an email address, maybe of the chair of the search committee, associated with the position ad you want to apply to.